# How to replace NA with set of values

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, replace, tibble

I have the following data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)


df <- tibble(
  source = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
  score = c(10, 5, NA, 3, NA ) ) 


df
```

It looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  source score
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 a         10 . # current max value
2 b          5
3 c         NA
4 d          3
5 e         NA
```

What I want to do is to replace `NA` in score column with values ranging for existing `max  + n` onwards. Where `n` range from 1 to total number of rows of the `df`

Resulting in this (hand-coded) :

```
  source score
  a         10
  b          5
  c         11 # obtained from 10 + 1
  d          3
  e         12 #  obtained from 10 + 2
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 10):

Another option :

```
transform(df, score = pmin(max(score, na.rm = TRUE) + 
                      cumsum(is.na(score)), score, na.rm = TRUE))

#  source score
#1      a    10
#2      b     5
#3      c    11
#4      d     3
#5      e    12
```

If you want to do this in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(score = pmin(max(score, na.rm = TRUE) + 
                      cumsum(is.na(score)), score, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 6):

A base R solution

```
df$score[is.na(df$score)] <- seq(which(is.na(df$score))) + max(df$score,na.rm = TRUE)
```

such that

```
> df
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  source score
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 a         10
2 b          5
3 c         11
4 d          3
5 e         12
```

Comment: Already the most concise but could shorten `seq(which(is.na(df$score)))` to `1:sum(is.na(df$score))`

Comment: @sindri_baldur thanks. that one has been offered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/60222864/12158757

Answer (score 6):

Here is a `dplyr` approach,

```
df %>% 
 mutate(score = replace(score, 
                       is.na(score), 
                       (max(score, na.rm = TRUE) + (cumsum(is.na(score))))[is.na(score)])
                       )
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 2
>   source score
>   <chr>  <dbl>
> 1 a         10
> 2 b          5
> 3 c         11
> 4 d          3
> 5 e         12
> ```

Answer (score 4):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at("score", ~ ifelse(is.na(.), max(., na.rm = TRUE) + cumsum(is.na(.)), .))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  source score
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 a         10
2 b          5
3 c         11
4 d          3
5 e         12
```

Answer (score 3):

A `dplyr` solution.

```
df %>%
  mutate(na_count = cumsum(is.na(score)),
         score = ifelse(is.na(score), max(score, na.rm = TRUE) + na_count, score)) %>%
  select(-na_count)
## A tibble: 5 x 2
#  source score
#  <chr>  <dbl>
#1 a         10
#2 b          5
#3 c         11
#4 d          3
#5 e         12
```

Answer (score 2):

Another one, quite similar to ThomasIsCoding's solution:

```
> df$score[is.na(df$score)]<-max(df$score, na.rm=T)+(1:sum(is.na(df$score)))
> df
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  source score
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 a         10
2 b          5
3 c         11
4 d          3
5 e         12
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite elegant as compared to the base R solutions, but still possible:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

max.score = df[, max(score, na.rm = TRUE)]
df[is.na(score), score :=(1:.N) + max.score]
```

Or in one line but a bit slower:

```
df[is.na(score), score := (1:.N) + df[, max(score, na.rm = TRUE)]]
df
   source score
1:      a    10
2:      b     5
3:      c    11
4:      d     3
5:      e    12
```